# java servlet w/ netbeans printing results from java derby db

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans-7, derby

using netbeans I created a web application, html form with submit button leading to a servlet. I would like to print the results of my derby db. Currently when I run it, the html page loads fine but the submit link to this servlet gives "SQLException caught : Connection authentication failure occurred. Reason: userid or password invalid." I checked the db credentials and user is correct and password is checked off as remember.

Please see below servlet code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection con = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       ResultSet rs = null;

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/movies;user=tb");
            stmt = con.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TB.MOVIES");

        while (rs.next()) {
        String s = rs.getString("TITLE");
        //float n = rs.getFloat("Age");
        out.println(s + "   ");
        }

            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)

        {

          out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());

        }

      catch(SQLException e)

        {

          out.println("SQLException caught : " + e.getMessage());

        }
        finally {            
            out.close();
```

Comment: _password is checked off as remember_ Checked off as remember for which session? You need to login once for it to remember you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it gave me the write idea